# after pressing a button it should open a JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, cardlayout

```
package garage;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Jela
 */
public class VehicleParts extends JPanel {

    public VehicleParts() {
     //super();
        //JPanel container = new JPanel();
        JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel card2 = new JPanel();

        JButton buttonOne = new JButton("Parts");
        JButton buttonTwo = new JButton("Stock");
        JButton buttonThree = new JButton("Supplier");


        add(buttonOne);
        add(buttonTwo);
        add(buttonThree);


    }

}
```

When pressing buttonOne, it should open up a jpanel on the same frame and should be able to go back to the frame, but somehow the buttons are not showing up. THis is not my main class. If anyone has some tips, please help. It should work something like this

### Stock  |  Parts |  Supplier |

```
                         -
                         -
      PANEL  1           -
                         -
                         -
                         -
                         -
  "Previous" "NEXT"      -
```

==========================   =
If pressing a button like next it should go to panel 2, under the parts tab

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
This is my main class
    package garage;

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Jela
 */
public class Garage extends JPanel {



  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Garage Management System");

  final static JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  final static CustomerAccounts customerPanel = new CustomerAccounts();
  final static DiagnosisAndRepair diagnosisPanel = new DiagnosisAndRepair();
  final static ScheduledMaintenance maintenancePanel = new ScheduledMaintenance();
  final static VehicleParts partsPanel = new VehicleParts();
  final static VehicleRecords recordsPanel = new VehicleRecords();


  CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

  public Garage(){
        tabbedPane.addTab("CustomerAccounts", customerPanel);
        tabbedPane.addTab("DiagnosisAndRepair", diagnosisPanel);
        tabbedPane.addTab("ScheduledMaintenance", maintenancePanel);
        tabbedPane.addTab("VehicleParts", partsPanel);
        tabbedPane.addTab("VehicleRecords", recordsPanel);
        //add(tabbedPane);



        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    frame.add(tabbedPane);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);



    }





    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Garage g = new Garage();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are stacking a new card on top of the current card every time you add another card.

```
card1.add(buttonOne);
card1.add(buttonTwo);
card1.add(buttonThree);
```

Doing this will display the last card added.

From java docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html

> It treats each component in the container as a card. Only one card is visible at a time, and the container acts as a stack of cards. The first component added to a CardLayout object is the visible component when the container is first displayed.

Something like this should work:

```
public class Cards() {

    private JPanel cardPanel;

    Cards() {
        cardPanel = makeCardPanel();
    }

private JPanel makeCardPanel() {
    JPanel card1 = new JPanel();

    JButton button1 = new JButton("button1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("button1");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("button1");

    card1.add(button1);
    card1.add(button2);
    card1.add(button3);

    JPanel card2 = new JPanel();

    JButton buttonA = new JButton("buttonA");
    card2.add(buttonA);

    // Repeat the above for the cards and buttons

    JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    cardPanel.add(card1, "First Card");
    cardPanel.add(card2, "Second Card");

    // Add the rest of the cards.

    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                ((CardLayout)cardPanel.getLayout()).show(cardPanel, "Second Card");


            }

        });

    buttonA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                ((CardLayout)mainPanel.getLayout()).show(cardPanel, "First Card");


            }

        });

    return cardPanel;
}

public JPanel getCardPanel() { return cardPanel; }
}
```

And then in your `Garage()` do:

```
public Garage(){
        Cards cards = new Cards();

        tabbedPane.addTab("CustomerAccounts", customerPanel);
        tabbedPane.addTab("DiagnosisAndRepair", diagnosisPanel);
        tabbedPane.addTab("ScheduledMaintenance", maintenancePanel);
        tabbedPane.addTab("VehicleParts", partsPanel);
        tabbedPane.addTab("VehicleRecords", recordsPanel);


        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        frame.add(tabbedPane);
        frame.add(cards.getCardPanel());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: how do i avoid overwriting it?

Comment: i want three buttons in card1

Comment: tried your method, but nothing seems to come up on the screen when i run it

Comment: Well remember with a card layout you are adding cards and you have to explicitly show the card you're interested in.  As for nothing coming up, did you add  `mainPanel` to the frame?

Comment: if i add mainPanel to my frame, then tabbedPane would be overwritten

Comment: @JelaxshanJehanathan can you help me to isolate the problem you are having?  Is it showing buttons or getting the next card to display?

Comment: @JelaxshanJehanathan I modified by code to give you a more simple solution that you can modify for your code.  Good luck

Comment: @JelaxshanJehanathan did you do `container.add(mainPanel)`?

Comment: thanks for your help @inquisitor, however i tried using your example with no luck, it produces a blank screen, with no buttons showing

Comment: @JelaxshanJehanathan from your example.  If nothing is showing up its because something isn't being added.

Comment: @JelaxshanJehanathan I see what your problem is.  First of all, get rid of container since we aren't using that anymore.  `mainPanel` will hold all the cards.  Next you need to create a panel that will hold your tabbedPane AND your cards.  Then you add that panel to the frame.

Comment: ok, however my tabbedPane is in the main class, so would i have to create a panel in my main?

Comment: code is working, however the buttons are appearing on the same window as the jtabbedPane. THE Buttons should only appear when the VehicleParts tab is clicked

Comment: @JelaxshanJehanathan add a ChangeListener to the tab that has the VehcileParts and have it display the cards with the buttons.

Comment: is there another way of doing it?

Comment: check code at the top, i changed it, i just want another jpanel to work with when clicking on each button in the vehicle parts tab

Answer (score 0):

**after** you add the buttons to the panel you need to do the followings:

```
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```